# Infinite root out of x

Tags: radicals

I and my friend were sitting in the maths lesson and we suddenly came up with what  infinite root out of x is equal to. And we came up with this this equation:

$$
\sqrt[\infty]{x} = 1+ (x-1)×10^{-\infty}
$$

I wonder if this makes any sense. (Im 10th former, and sorry if this is an out of topic question)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$. Write it as

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x}=\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{1/n}
$$ 
You see that the power $1/n$ goes to $0$ when $n$ increases so $x^{1/n}$ goes to $x^0$ which is $1$.

Comment: So if i understood correctly this equation isnt right, is it?

Comment: @yamahamm how did you derive it?

Comment: It is since since $10^{-\infty}=0 \implies (x-1)*10^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: @kingW3 hmm, it returns the right result, but there are many function satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=1$...

Comment: Uhm... when you keep pressing root sogn in calculator, you sooner or later get one. But the number that you get is rounded. So i took number 1 as a base, because any root out of 1 is 1, so of we take 1 in this equation, we will get one, but if we take for example 2, we get something like 2,0000000... and i took 10^- ∞ because it has to be very small digit

Comment: Oh, didnt know that KingW3.  Then yes, im wrong

Comment: @yamahamm sounds, let's say, "constructed".

Comment: @yamahamm anyway welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: I know draks :) i havent studied university maths, so this was guess-made equation. Thats why i asked your opinion about that :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[\infty]{x}$ can be interpreted as

$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[a]{x}$

and $1+(x-1)\cdot 10^{-\infty}$ can be interpreted as

$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow\infty}(1+\large\frac{x-1}{10^a})$

In this sense the given equation is true since

$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[a]{x}= \lim\limits_{a\rightarrow\infty}(1+\large\frac{x-1}{10^a})=1$

Comment: But does this work with numbers bigger than one?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by numbers bigger than one? The "infinite root" of ANY (positive) number is 1.

Comment: This equation holds for all $x$ bigger than zero..

Comment: @Danny so you mean that with any number bigger than 0 equation is equal to 1, or this formula has some sense?

Comment: Yes. Both sides of your equation are equal to 1 for $x>0$. The sense of your equation is another question.. it is not difficult to construct equations like yours, but maybe there is an interesting interpretation.. :)

Comment: Ok, thats all i wanted to know, thanks :)